# In the way / in a way / the way / as

Tags: conjunctions

Here's a context.

A: I ordered a product and it was delivered two days ago. But the design of the product was not what I had in mind. I asked for the restaurant's name to be printed larger than this and the restaurant's phone number was supposed to be written on the bottom, so customers could see it to make a reservation.

B:

> 1.After getting your message, I redesigned ***in the way*** you asked me to.
>
> 2.After getting your message, I redesigned ***the way*** you asked me to.
>
> 3.After getting your message, I redesigned ***as*** you asked me to.
>
> 4.After getting your message, I redesigned ***in a way*** you asked me to.

I think #123 are right and the same meaning, so I can use whatever I want. But #4 is not referring to the definite way that has been mentioned above using '***A'***. So #4 is not appropriate. Am I right to think this way?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [As / The way / In the way - all possible and the same meaning here, right?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61257/as-the-way-in-the-way-all-possible-and-the-same-meaning-here-right)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct,  1, 2, and 3 are all acceptable and 4 is not. Personally, I would say 2.

However, they are all missing a pronoun. "Redesigned" needs an object so you can't say

> I redesigned the way you asked me to.

You must specify *what* you redesigned.

> I redesigned *it* the way you asked me to.